# firebase and ionic: modify the password reset template (from auth) to send verifications etc?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

My native language isn't supported by firebase's auth templates, so I was wondering if it'd be possible to modify the only modifiable template, which is the password reset template, to also send verification and email address change emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. You can't modify the template content to be a verification email template when the link will always be the password reset link. You can just file a feature request for your language support. Reach out to the Firebase official support team about this.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing